# HTML table with fixed header/columns - css solution - not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, fixed-header-tables

I'm working on a project where the client wants sticky headers/columns on his table. But I can't use a real script for this cause this project have already to many objects in page and I'm losing speed and stuffs like that.

What I succeed so far is to creat a hybrid of css with javascript in which I scroll left/top my elements after the table scroll.

Working well even in IE 9, to not cover Opera, Chrome, Safari, Maxthon; but sadly this doesn't work in FF so I need a bit of help to solve this.

I'll post here my fiddle result page: http://jsfiddle.net/kordosoft/7v4RZ/21/embedded/result/
Working copy of fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/kordosoft/7v4RZ/21/

If you will open it in different browsers this will work except FF.

Sticky headers: 1st 2 rows; Sticky columns: 1st 2 columns;

JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("valuation")[0].onscroll = function ()
{
        var _left = document.getElementsByClassName("valuation")[0].scrollLeft;
        jQuery('.valuation td[column="A"],.valuation td[column="B"]').css('left', _left);

        var _top = document.getElementsByClassName("valuation")[0].scrollTop;
        jQuery('.valuation td[row="1"],.valuation td[row="3"]').css('top', _top);

}
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-spacing: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: #4D4F6E;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
}

td {
    position: relative;
}

.valuation {
    display: block;
    overflow: scroll;
    max-height: 400px;
    width: 700px;
}

.donotshow{display:none;}

.valuation td[column="A"], .valuation td[column="B"]
{
    min-width: 190px!important;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-right: 1px dashed #d6dae1;
}

.valuation td
{
    min-width: 75px;   
}

.valuation td[column="A"], .valuation td[column="B"]
{
     left:0;z-index:2;
}


 .valuation td[row="1"], .valuation td[row="3"]
  {
    z-index:2;        
    top:0;        
 }

.valuation td[row="1"][column="B"], .valuation td[row="3"][column="B"],.valuation td[row="1"][column="A"], .valuation td[row="3"][column="A"]
 {
    z-index:3;
 }
.valuation tr[row="3"]
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.valuation tr[row="1"] td, .valuation tr[row="4"] td, .valuation tr[row="30"] td, .valuation tr[row="52"] td, .valuation tr[row="82"] td, .valuation tr[row="92"] td, .valuation tr[row="95"] td, .valuation tr[row="104"] td, .valuation tr[row="118"] td, .valuation tr[row="140"] td, .valuation tr[row="146"] td, .valuation tr[row="149"] td, .valuation tr[row="200"] td, .valuation tr[row="220"] td, .valuation tr[row="234"] td
{
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none!important;
    color: #383A6A;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff!important;
    background: rgb(213,222,239); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(213,222,239,1) 0%, rgba(192,196,211,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(213,222,239,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(192,196,211,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(213,222,239,1) 0%,rgba(192,196,211,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(213,222,239,1) 0%,rgba(192,196,211,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(213,222,239,1) 0%,rgba(192,196,211,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(213,222,239,1) 0%,rgba(192,196,211,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d5deef', endColorstr='#c0c4d3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.valuation tr:nth-child(2n) td
{
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.valuation tr:nth-child(2n+1) td
{
    background-color: #F4F6FA;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="valuation">
    <tbody>
        <tr row="1">
            <td column="A" row="1" sheet="valuation">Valuation for:<span class="companynamelabel">-</span>
            </td>
            <td column="B" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="J" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="K" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="L" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="M" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="N" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="O" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="P" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="Q" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="R" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="S" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="T" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="U" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="V" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="1" sheet="valuation"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr row="3">
            <td column="A" row="3" sheet="valuation">Years</td>
            <td column="B" row="3" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy-9">2005</span>
            </td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy-8">2006</span>
            </td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy-7">2007</span>
            </td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy-6">2008</span>
            </td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy-5">2009</span>
            </td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy-4">2010</span>
            </td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy-3">2011</span>
            </td>
            <td column="J" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy-2">2012</span>
            </td>
            <td column="K" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy-1">2013</span>
            </td>
            <td column="L" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy0">2014</span>
            </td>
            <td column="M" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy1">2015</span>
            </td>
            <td column="N" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy2">2016</span>
            </td>
            <td column="O" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy3">2017</span>
            </td>
            <td column="P" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy4">2018</span>
            </td>
            <td column="Q" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy5">2019</span>
            </td>
            <td column="R" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy6">2020</span>
            </td>
            <td column="S" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy7">2021</span>
            </td>
            <td column="T" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy8">2022</span>
            </td>
            <td column="U" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy9">2023</span>
            </td>
            <td column="V" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy10">2024</span>
            </td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy11">2025</span>
            </td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="3" sheet="valuation"><span class="fy12">2026</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr row="4">
            <td column="A" row="4" sheet="valuation">Operating Free Cash Flow</td>
            <td column="B" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="J" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="K" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="L" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="M" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="N" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="O" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="P" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="Q" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="R" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="S" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="T" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="U" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="V" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="4" sheet="valuation"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr row="6">
            <td column="A" row="6" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="B" row="6" sheet="valuation">Net Income</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="J" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="K" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="L" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="M" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="N" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="O" row="6" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="P" row="6" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="Q" row="6" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="R" row="6" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="S" row="6" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="T" row="6" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="U" row="6" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="V" row="6" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="6" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="6" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr row="7">
            <td column="A" row="7" sheet="valuation">+</td>
            <td column="B" row="7" sheet="valuation">Net Interest Expense after Tax</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="J" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="K" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="L" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="M" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="N" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="O" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="P" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="Q" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="R" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="S" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="T" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="U" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="V" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="7" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
        </tr>            
        <tr row="42">
            <td column="A" row="42" sheet="valuation">+</td>
            <td column="B" row="42" sheet="valuation">Goodwill Amortisation</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="J" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="K" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="L" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="M" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="N" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="O" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="P" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="Q" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="R" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="S" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="T" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="U" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="V" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="42" sheet="valuation">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr row="43">
            <td column="A" row="43" sheet="valuation">+</td>
            <td column="B" row="43" sheet="valuation">D Provision</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="43" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="J" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="K" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="L" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="M" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="N" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="O" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="P" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="Q" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="R" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="S" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="T" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="U" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="V" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="43" sheet="valuation">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr row="44">
            <td column="A" row="44" sheet="valuation">-</td>
            <td column="B" row="44" sheet="valuation">Gains /(Losses) on Assets Sold after Tax</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="J" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="K" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="L" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="M" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="N" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="O" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="P" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="Q" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="R" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="S" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="T" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="U" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="V" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="44" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr row="45">
            <td column="A" row="45" sheet="valuation">-</td>
            <td column="B" row="45" sheet="valuation">Extraordinary Items</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="J" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="K" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="L" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="M" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="N" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="O" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="P" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="Q" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="R" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="S" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="T" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="U" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="V" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="45" sheet="valuation">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr row="46">
            <td column="A" row="46" sheet="valuation">+</td>
            <td column="B" row="46" sheet="valuation">Deferred Tax</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="J" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="K" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="L" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="M" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="N" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="O" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="P" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="Q" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="R" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="S" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="T" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="U" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="V" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="46" sheet="valuation">0</td>
        </tr>            
        <tr row="48">
            <td column="A" row="48" sheet="valuation">+</td>
            <td column="B" row="48" sheet="valuation">Change in Capitalised R &amp; D after Tax</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="48" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="J" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="K" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="L" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="M" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="N" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="O" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="P" row="48" sheet="valuation">N/A</td>
            <td column="Q" row="48" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="R" row="48" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="S" row="48" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="T" row="48" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="U" row="48" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="V" row="48" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="48" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="48" sheet="valuation">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr row="49">
            <td column="A" row="49" sheet="valuation">=</td>
            <td column="B" row="49" sheet="valuation">NOPAT (Financing)</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="J" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="K" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="L" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="M" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="N" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="O" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="P" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="Q" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="R" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="S" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="T" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="U" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td column="V" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="49" sheet="valuation">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr row="52">
            <td column="A" row="52" sheet="valuation">Capital</td>
            <td column="B" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="C" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="D" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="E" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="F" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="G" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="H" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="I" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="J" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="K" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="L" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="M" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="N" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="O" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="P" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="Q" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="R" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="S" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="T" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="U" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td column="V" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="W" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
            <td class="donotshow" column="X" row="52" sheet="valuation"></td>
        </tr>                   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you thought about simply [embedding a google spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/55244?hl=en)?  This would also give all the benefits of a full spreadsheet application.

Comment: @Tims - I have multiple reasons to NOT use google spreadsheets - UI, formulas, speed&performance, number of data, how the data are processed, the output filtering... so no way... maybe it will work for 1k linked cells...but on 400k cells linked no way, I don't want my client browser to crash when he tries to input data into the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, the problem is only in firefox, I guess we can cheat a little bit and use CSS transforms with the prefix `-moz` and other browsers will just ignore it. So something like

```
jQuery('.valuation td[column="A"],.valuation td[column="B"]').css({
    'left': _left,
    '-moz-transform': "translate3d(" + _left + "px,0px,0)"
});

jQuery('.valuation td[row="1"],.valuation td[row="3"]').css({
    'top': _top,
    '-moz-transform': "translate3d(0px," + _top + "px,0)"
});

//because there's only only one css property, row will overwrite column above.
//so the code below selects the case where it has both translateX and translate Y
jQuery('.valuation td[row="1"],.valuation td[row="3"]')
     .filter('.valuation td[column="A"],.valuation td[column="B"]')
     .css('-moz-transform', "translate3d(" + _left + "px," + _top + "px,0)");
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7v4RZ/26/)

Answer (score 0):

I would put the headers outside the table, maybe in its own table or using divs.  Next put the table inside a div with overflow: auto.  Best of all there's no Javascript required so performance should be far better.